# Why doesn't my Kivy label text fit in the label?

Tags: kivy

I have a big knowledge gap about how Kivy sizes the various elements, and it is being resistant to my attempts to fix it.

Here is my `stopwatch.kv` file

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<StopWatch>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .2, .2, .2, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: "A long piece of text #1"
            size: self.texture_size
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .1, .1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        Label:
            text: "A long piece of text #2"
            size: self.texture_size
            text_size: root.width, None
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5, .5, .1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

Here is `main.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class StopWatch(Widget):
    pass


class StopWatchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sw = StopWatch()
        return sw


if __name__ == '__main__':
    StopWatchApp().run()
```

I have figured out the size of the *window* (on my desktop) is, by default, unrelated to its contents. Okay.

I have figured out the size of the `BoxLayout` is, by default, unrelated to the window size. Instead, it is large enough to enclose its children widgets. Okay.

I have figured out that the size of a `Label` is, by default, unrelated to the size of its text contents. Instead, I *think* it is 100x100, but I haven't found that documented.

If you want a label to be big enough to cover the text (and hence the BoxLayout to cover the text), you have to specify:

```
size: self.texture_size
```

Okay. But I do that for the first label, and it still exceeds its label size (which I use a rectangle coloured red to visualise.)

So, I try to specify the text_size in the second label - making it the full width of the window - but its text doesn't appear at all!

[image: Screenshot]

I know I am missing something obvious, but reading the manuals hasn't helped.

Comment: So, (using your words), the `Label`'s (and also any widget's) default size is 100x100, and the `FloatLayout` is "large enough to enclose its children widgets" (100x200). So, how do you expect the much bigger text to fit in it? You have to resize *something*. If you post a [mcve], I could try to give you a way to do it..

Comment: @noEmbryo: This might be part of the understanding gap: when I set `size: self.texture_size`, I think I *am* resizing something - the label to match the needs of the long text. Is that not the case?

Comment: I thought a BoxLayout with two labels was a minimal reproducible example - do you want the Python code too? It is pretty much boilerplate instantiation of the StopWatch widget.

Comment: Yes, we want to see a [mcve]. You haven't even included the definition of the `StopWatch` class, which is likely the problem.

Comment: @JohnAnderson: Oh, okay. Done. If the problem is there, I have been looking in completely the wrong place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `StopWatch` extends `Widget`, and `Widget` is not intended as a container. See the [Widget Class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#module-kivy.uix.widget).

Note the part that says:

- A Widget is not a Layout: it will not change the position or the size
  of its children. If you want control over positioning or sizing, use
  a Layout.
- The default size of a widget is (100, 100). This is only changed if
  the parent is a Layout. For example, if you add a Label inside a
  Button, the label will not inherit the button’s size or position
  because the button is not a Layout: it’s just another Widget.
- The default size_hint is (1, 1). If the parent is a Layout, then the
  widget size will be the parent layout’s size.

So, your `StopWatch` will be size `(100,100)`, and your `Labels` are wider than that. A simple solution is to change your `StopWatch` to extend a `Layout` like this:

```
class StopWatch(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

Then you can rewrite your `kv` as:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<StopWatch>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .2, .2, .2, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text: "A long piece of text #1"
        size: self.texture_size
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .1, .1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    Label:
        text: "A long piece of text #2"
        size: self.texture_size
        text_size: root.width, None
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Note that the `BoxLayout` has been removed from the `kv`, since `StopWatch` is now a `BoxLayout`. Also, note that your `size` properties of the `Labels` in your `kv` will have no effect unless you set `size_hint` to `(None, None)`, since `size_hint` takes precedence over `size`.

Comment: OMG! That is a game-changer. I have totally been barking up the wrong tree. Thank you.

Comment: I can see the genesis of my mistake. I started with the [pong example](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html), which uses a Widget as the root level object, but I didn't realise that was a design decision relevant for the game, but was general boilerplate.